# Trying to create a label for each point on a graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, scatter-plot, plot-annotations

I am creating a scatter graph of UK counties crime rate vs population and I want to have each point labelled with the name of the county so i can visualise it and see the relative safety of each county(using numpy, panda and matplotlib)

I haven't tried anything yet but i know you can use the annotate() function to get the numbers up

Comment: what about doing something similar to a cloropleth map?
https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `annotate()` function from matplotlib. Here's an exemple

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data from CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('uk_counties_data.csv')

# Create scatter plot
plt.scatter(data['population'], data['crime_rate'])

# Add labels to each point
for i in range(len(data)):
    plt.annotate(data['county'][i], xy=(data['population'][i], data['crime_rate'][i]))

# Set plot title and axis labels
plt.title('UK Counties Crime Rate vs Population')
plt.xlabel('Population')
plt.ylabel('Crime Rate')

# Display plot
plt.show()
```

I used some data in this csv file:

```
county,population,crime_rate
Bedfordshire,664527,56.2
Berkshire,909902,47.5
Bristol,449300,74.9
Buckinghamshire,803577,47.8
Cambridgeshire,657751,49.1
Cheshire,1170194,71.6
Cornwall,568210,57.9
Cumbria,498888,60.5
Derbyshire,1065655,66.2
Devon,789908,57.4
Dorset,376426,52.8
Durham,526980,73.4
East Sussex,767415,55.9
Essex,1461700,68.2
Gloucestershire,626107,52.7
Greater London,8980170,85.6
Greater Manchester,2830000,96.2
Hampshire,1858000,52.4
Herefordshire,191031,46.2
Hertfordshire,1188077,50.1
Isle of Wight,141538,50.8
Kent,1661000,61.5
Lancashire,1461000,76.2
Leicestershire,715900,77.9
Lincolnshire,771349,61.1
Merseyside,1431000,97.4
Norfolk,899016,50.9
North Yorkshire,626964,56.3
Northamptonshire,723000,66.2
Northumberland,320000,57.9
Nottinghamshire,1152995,74.8
Oxfordshire,687927,54.6
Rutland,39895,37.4
Shropshire,320274,46.8
Somerset,560000,56.6
South Yorkshire,1400000,85.2
Staffordshire,1121253,71.3
Suffolk,758000,52.5
Surrey,1220000,49.9
Tyne and Wear,1336000,89.6
Warwickshire,557636,52.4
West Midlands,2900000,86.4
West Sussex,850000,48.7
West Yorkshire,2341000,82.1
Wiltshire,465000,43.2
Worcestershire,588000,52.8
```

and get this output

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i9IQ.png)